# Calling google.script.run with Namespace Functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, javascript-namespaces

I've been migrating an old javascript project to GAS and am hitting a blocker on trying to run namespace functions from the client-side web app. Quick code example:

```
var foo = function() {
  function doBar() {
    //do stuff
  }

  function doBang() {
    //do stuff
  }

  return {
  bar:doBar,
  bang:doBang
  }
}();
```

While this would be easy to call on the server side through `foo.bar()`, I have hit a wall in trying to speak to these functions from my web app. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
<script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).foo.bar();
  function callback() {
    //do stuff
  }
</script>
```

But alas this does not seem to work. Is there something I am missing, or another way to get this working without having some form of handler function, not contained in a namespace, which passes through to my namespaces?

As this is a project migration, I have a very well structured but huge, set of namespaces; This would require a very long and robust hander function, so I would like to avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: Why not just pass as a parameter? `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).foo(internalFunctionName)`

Comment: @TheMaster unless I am misunderstanding you, that's what I meant by using a handler or router function. A nightmare to do in this case, because I have many hundreds of routes throughout my namespaces and I am not overly excited about using evals.

Comment: Not seeing the issue. Seems to me like a two line modification? `return ({
  bar:doBar,
  bang:doBang
  })[internalFunctionName]()`?

Comment: @TheMaster I am not sure that I am following what you mean. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how a handler function would be hard by [edit]ing your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need that handler function. Apps Script doesn't understand you are calling a server-side function if you add the dot, and so you get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bar')

#### Feature request:

I'd suggest you to request this feature using [this Issue Tracker template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113), if you'd like to see this implemented.